# Does Sivir's shield work against Draven's q?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering if the spell shield would shield against Draven's q, since it is an auto attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spell shields cannot block Draven's Spinning Axe, however;
The bonus damage will be negated if the auto attack is  dodged,  blocked,  parried, or if the attack misses. However, the axe will still bounce off.

Comment: Having played a Sivir v. Draven matchup numerous times I can confirm this. For some reason it doesn't work like other on-hit skills like Nasus Q and doesn't get blocked by spell shields.